# Why is devise session not persisted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

Some users in our Rails application are unable to sign in/up because the session can't be persisted. This is totally random and I'm not able to reproduce it. Is there anything I should monitor to narrow down the problem? Is there any browser configuration that I should ask the the users?

App is running rails-3.2.8 and devise-2.1.2

We are storing session into memcached, allowing subdomains:

> Authentication::Application.config.session_store
>   ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore, :namespace => '_sessions', :key
>   => '_cb_session_m', :expire_after => 2.weeks, :domain => 'my_domain.com'